# Javascript functions - pulling more than what's been given

Tags: javascript, object, closures

This is pure curiosity. Let's write an object:

```
 var display = { res1:{ w:640, h:480 }, res2:{ w:320, h:240 }, nores:{} };
```

Now from this object, we're sending the `nores` property to a function. Since `nores` is an object, whatever we change in `somefunction` is going to be seen later in `display.nores`:

```
 somefunction(display.nores);
```

Now here's the question. Does `somefunction()` has any form of access to `display`'s other properties (`res1` / `res2`) given that display is defined inside a closure and `somefunction()` was defined outside of that closure? I mean can it reference the whole `display` object just from its `nores` property that was passed as an argument?

Comment: Though I wrote it's not possible in js in my answer, do you know a language where it is possible? **maybe** C.

Comment: I'm not sure either. Maybe there's a `v8` crazy magic function somewhere that does it.

Comment: There is a good reason what's not possbile, encapsulation.

Comment: Well I kinda skimmed through v8's docs, no joy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does somefunction() has any form of access to display's other properties (res1 / res2) given that display is defined inside a closure and somefunction() was defined outside of that closure?

No

> I mean can it reference the whole display object just from its nores property that was passed as an argument?

There is no reverse relationship between the properties of an object and their values. The only way to find them would be to have access to the object and then to loop over it until you find a match.

Answer (score 2):

**No**, you can't get the outer object from the inner object.

You can't "play" with the references addresses in javascript, there is a good reason what's not allowed - **encapsulation** - you shouldn't be allowed touching things you didn't "recieve".

I don't know if there is a language where this kind of thing is possible, Maybe **Maybe** `C`.